# Typescript syntax: Check is string literal belongs to a type

Tags: typescript

I want to write something like this

```js
type ISomeType = 'one'|'two'|'more';

const bigBigBigDataType = {
   ...
   someValue: 'bla-bla' oneOf ISomeType;
   ...
}
```

This code will work with no compilation errors. But I want to find some syntax which will not allow as to write `bla-bla` into a `someValue` which must be of type `ISomeType`.

Create a type for `bigBigBigDataType` is not solution.

Comment: Why is the solution `const someValue: ISomeType = 'bla-bla';` not acceptable?

Comment: By using a cast, you've instructed the compiler to not warn you about the type compatiblity; you've deliberately disabled that part of the type checking process. That's how it should work; `const someValue: ISomeType = 'bla-bla';` is the normal way of using the language - why is this not acceptable?

Comment: because sometimes I cannot define for big structure big type (just have no time). I want just create a type for a one node

Comment: edited question for more understanding

Comment: @YuriyGyerts You only have to setup your big data type structure once. Instead of thinking about it as a time waste, think of setting up those big data structures as an investment. (Keep in mind that you can autogenerate typescript interfaces from json structures as a good starting point.) You will benefit from compile-time checks in the long run. If you don't want those compile-time checks and don't want to use the type system as intended, you may as well may use `any` and lose a big benefit of writing TypeScript over JavaScript to begin with.

Comment: @k0pernikus I am not new in typescript. I know it is a good way todo typings in each part of code. But the question is another. Is any ways to do partial typings. Not all. No one will pay money to me if I will be do the best I can. And even more. It doesnt metter what types in other values. The only `someValue` type is interested to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can define interaface with index signature. 
based on your comment "Is any ways to do partial typings. Not all"

you can define one prop type and let other be whatever you want to

```
type ISomeType = 'one' | 'two' | 'more';
interface IPartial {
  someValue: ISomeType;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const bigBigBigDataType: IPartial = {
  someValue: 'asd', // Type '"asd"' is not assignable to type 'ISomeType'
  whateverYouWant: 1,
};
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have at the moment, but I want something another. Something like `'bla-bla' oneOf ISomeType`

Comment: i know what you want but it is not possible i think.

Comment: but you can still declare type in your cosnt, so no interface.... cosnt bigBigBigDataType: {someValue: ISomeType, [key: string]: any} = { ... }